# Time triggered Azure Function, how to connect with OneDrive or SharePoint

Tags: python, azure-functions

I am using a time triggered Azure Function to process csv files and store them in a SQL service.

There are a couple of actions involving OneDrive/ local files:

- Creating local logfile in OneDrive folder
- Reading files from multiple subdirectories
- Moving files after processing to different subdirectories

I currently access files in a couple of ways:

```
user = getpass.getuser()
extension = csv
directory = r"C:/Users/{}/Company/OneDrive folder/Subfolder1".format(user)
os.chdir(directory)
files = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

#etc..

shutil.move(directory+csvfile, targetdir)
```

These folders are all stored in OneDrive/ SharePoint, but I have trouble accessing them through Azure Functions and can only find .json related examples with workarounds.

Is there an easy way to translate the directories, preferably using my own account for access/ authorization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I’m Wayne Wang from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team!

Usually if you want your azure function access to sharepoint, you may have to

1. Create an application registration on you AAD for your function api
2. Give the access of the function to sharepoint

see  document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient

then you can use these Graph api after you got the auth token.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial

I would strongly recommend you use Logic App instead on this. It will be much easier to configure and not expensive on Onedrive and sharepoint accessing

The pipeline could be

1. Azure Logic App Start on timer
2. Logic app Call python function, python function save file in azure storage account
3. Logic app get response of file location in azure storage account, upload it to SP/1drv

it cost you 10 mins to configure.

Hope these ideas could help.

Wayne